# php date() functions producing unexpected output

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I'm trying to do some basic date and timestamp operations in PHP and have been getting unexpected results.  I'm trying to get a timestamp with just the year, month, and day of the month (i.e. the timestamp of a date at 12:00 A.M.) of the existing timestamp `$startDate`.  It was changing the date as well, though, as can be seen in the following code.

```
$startDateString = date("Y-M-j", $startDate);
$startDateTimestamp = strtotime($startDateString);
echo "$startDate == $startDateTimestamp ?<br>";
echo date("Y-M-j", $startDate)." == ".date("Y-M-j", $startDateTimestamp)." ?<br>";
```

This gives me the following output:

```
1299299589 == 1298952000 ?
2011-Mar-4 == 2011-Feb-28 ?
```

While I wouldn't expect the timestamps to be the same (as `$startDate` is not necessarily at 12:00 A.M.), I can't see how the calendar dates aren't the same.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to reference [the formats supported by strtotime](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php), among which you will fail to find Y-M-j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some short tests, I noticed that [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) is unable to parse the format `Y-M-j` properly. To fix this, use a standard format, such as [RFC822 date time format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.rfc822), [ISO-8601 date time format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.iso8601) or use `j-M-Y` instead.

Answer (score 2):

From the [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) documentation:

> A date/time string. Valid formats are explained in [Date and Time Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

As for the problem you are trying to solve, you can pass other things to strtotime, like [relative formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

```
strtotime('midnight', $startDate);
```

As an example, to echo midnight (you can also use today if midnight is confusing) of the current time:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('midnight'));
```

Both 'today' and 'midnight'

> The time is set to 00:00:00

Of course I am a big fan of the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object.

```
$date = new DateTime($startDate);
$date->modify('midnight');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: This was really helpful as well.  If only I could select two correct answers!

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the "Y-m-d" format for similar tasks and that works:

```
$startDateString = date("Y-m-d", $startDate);
$startDateTimestamp = strtotime($startDateString);
echo "$startDate == $startDateTimestamp ?<br>";
echo date("Y-m-d", $startDate)." == ".date("Y-m-d", $startDateTimestamp)." ?<br>";
```